# Time for Reading the Meggilah

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, halacha, zemanim

1. What is the optimal time for reading the Meggilah

   1. By day?
   2. By night?
2. When is the first and last halachicly acceptable time for each?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The earliest time for the night reading is after nightfall the latest you can hear at night is halachic dawn.By day the earliest is after sunrise the latest by day is before sunset.
[Source-http://www.dinonline.org/](http://www.dinonline.org/2011/02/06/purim-the-megilah/)

Comment: I think this is a case of Ta'ah Be'dvar Mishna: see Mishna Megillah 2:4 [For those who don't get the joke see Rama on YD 242:31]